# Perceptron, two different algorithms

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

Try to re-visit perceptron material I run into two different algorithms. This is the first one:

[image: This is the first one:]

The second one just says :

> Whenever an example X is misclassified do
>   W_new = W_old + X or W_new = W_old - X dippendes on the relative position
>   of X with respect to the hyperplane (usually line in the case of 2D).

Is the 2nd one just a special case of the 1st where the learning rate is 1, 
or those are two different algorithms? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 2nd case is the same as the first, when the learning rate = 1.

[image]